# Program to find specific word and then ouput the line of that word in a text file

Tags: c

So my problem is that I have a text file with names and services that they ordered. I need to search a file for a given name and then output a line on which that name is located. Here's my code, although it outputs the content of a line and not the actual line

```
printf("What is the customer's name\n");
scanf("%s", &name);
f = fopen("C:\\customer_info.txt", "r");
   while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f) != NULL) 
      {
      if (strstr(line, name) != NULL) 
         {
          printf("%s", line);
         }
      }
```

Comment: you may probably be interested in ``strstr`` or ``strcasestr``

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, providing a [example]. Additionally, show us some sample input, what you expect, and what you get instead.

Comment: You could just increment a counter variable in the `while`, and print the value if that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 100

int main(void) {
    char word_to_find[MAX], line[MAX];
    FILE *fp = fopen("customer_info.txt", "r");
    FILE *fp_write = fopen("customers_new_added.txt", "a");
    unsigned short FLAG_FOUND = 0;

    if (!fp) {
        printf("Failed to open the file.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Enter a customer name to find: ");
    fgets(word_to_find, MAX, stdin);


    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) { // reading till NULL of File
        if (strstr(line, word_to_find) != NULL) { // finding till NULL of Line
            printf("%s", line);
            fprintf(fp_write, "%s", line); // writing the entire line into the file
            FLAG_FOUND = 1; // found something in the line?
        }
    }

    if (!FLAG_FOUND) // if zero
        printf("Sorry, no matches were found...\n");

    fclose(fp_write);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

---

### Explanation

The statement:

```
strstr(line, word_to_find) != NULL
```

Will only become `NULL` when it reaches `NULL`, in other words, the customer name should be given in the last position of lines.

My `customer_info.txt` is as follows:

```
PRICE       SERVICE     CUSTOMER_NAME
=========================================
1250.00     Premium     John_Doe
750.00      Pro Pack    Lorem_Ipsum
1800.00     Grand       Johnny_Doe
```

The program works like:

```
$ g++ -o pro pro.cpp; ./pro
Enter a customer name to find: John_Doe
1250.00         Premium         John_Doe // LET LINE_X
```

The mentioned `LINE_X` will be written into `customers_new_added.txt` (creates if doesn't exists).

`customers_new_added.txt` is as follows now:

```
1250.00     Premium     John_Doe
```

**The end of file must contain a new line or the last line will not be read.**